# Definition of a smooth projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is the definition of a smooth projective curve given in following link(page 8, 2.3 Function fields):

http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2013-50-01/S0273-0979-2012-01387-3/S0273-0979-2012-01387-3.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smooth means that it is not singular http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve#Singularities

Projective means that it is in projective space instead of affine space
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve#Plane_projective_curves

Curve means that it isn't a surface or something bigger (like a surface)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gage. Anyway, according to the link i share, a curve means a variety of dimension 1, doesn't it?"

Comment: Yes. For example a curve in $A^3$ is something like $z =0$ and $y = x^2$ while a variety of a higher dimension would be $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1$. This second example is a  a variety of dimension > 1 (specifically a surface).